# ReleasePayment via API results in PX.Data.PXActionDisabledException

Tags: api, rest, acumatica

When attempting to release a Customer Refund (AR302000) via the web service endpoint ~/entity/Default/18.200.001/Payment/ReleasePayment I receive the following exception message:

```json
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Operation failed",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXInvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Invoke(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.InvokeImpl(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.Invoke(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, String objectName, HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.InvokeAction(String objectName, String actionName, ActionInvocation invocation)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "The Release button is disabled.",
        "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXActionDisabledException",
        "stackTrace": "   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__28.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()"
    }
}
```

The request body looks like this:

```json
{
   "entity": {
      "ReferenceNbr": {
        "value": "FTNHQ-RP0205826"
      }
   }
}
```

I have checked that the release button is enabled when viewing the payment document:

[image: Customer Refund]

The error on this endpoint, and on the /Invoice/ReleaseInvoice started happening after upgrading from 2019R1 (19.100.0122) to 2020R1 (20.108.0019). Note that I can do other create, read & updates just fine - it only seems to be the actions that are giving issues, e.g. the Customer Refund I'm trying to release here was created via the API.

At first, I thought it might have something to do with the new functionality on Control Account restrictions that were rolled out in 2019R2, but I have made sure to set up the sub-ledger settings on the Chart of Accounts list.

I have also reviewed the Trace requests using the profiler for the request, but am not able to decipher anything actionable from the list, see below.

[image: Trace for ~/entity/default/18.200.001/payment/releasepayment]

PS. I'm still able to run the above release actions on our production server (via the web services API) without any issues (as it's still on version 2019R1).

I have also tried to just release the Customer Refund via the normal UI on the web, and that works, so this is definitely a bit of a head-scratcher.

Any help/ideas will be highly appreciated.

Long Trace message from screenshot above:

```net
LINQ fallback! Consider rewriting your query.    at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo.ExecuteQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryProviderBase.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriodIDAttribute.ValidateRelatedToMainFinPeriods(PXCache cache, Object oldRow, Object newRow, Boolean externalCall, Nullable`1 newMainCalendarOrgID, Nullable`1 oldMainCalendarOrgID, FinPeriod newMainOrgFinPeriod)
   at PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriodIDAttribute.ValidatePeriodAndSourcesImpl(PXCache cache, Object oldRow, Object newRow, Boolean externalCall)
   at PX.Objects.GL.OrganizationDependedPeriodIDAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Objects.GL.OpenPeriodAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXRowPersisting.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
   at PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry.Persist()
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__2.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__28.MoveNext()
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Invoke(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean throwOnError)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.InvokeImpl(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, Boolean throwOnError)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.Invoke(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, String objectName, HttpRequestMessage request)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.InvokeAction(String objectName, String actionName, ActionInvocation invocation)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<>c.<ExecuteAsync>b__5_0(ActionInvoker innerInvoker)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<InvokeActionWithActionFilters>b__0()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthorizationFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.Owin.DependencyScopeHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.InvokeCore(IOwinContext context, IOwinRequest owinRequest, IOwinResponse owinResponse)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.InvokeCore(IOwinContext context, IOwinRequest owinRequest, IOwinResponse owinResponse)
   at PX.Owin.Startup.<<ConfigurationImpl>b__10_5>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at PX.Owin.Startup.<ConfigurationImpl>b__10_5(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 next)
   at PX.Logging.Enrichers.OwinExtensions.<>c.<<DisableAspNetCallbackEnricher>b__0_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at PX.Logging.Enrichers.OwinExtensions.<>c.<DisableAspNetCallbackEnricher>b__0_0(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.RunApp(Func`2 entryPoint, IDictionary`2 environment, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, StageAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are missing the Payment type - since it's one of the key fields it needs to be set in the body of your request. It would probably work without the Type if it was a standard Payment (type 'Payment') since this is the default in the screen, but in your case it is a Customer Refund.

I tested this locally and it works fine when doing HTTP POST to entity/Default/18.200.001/Payment/ReleasePayment:

```
{
   "entity": {
      "Type": {
        "value": "Customer Refund"
      },
      "ReferenceNbr": {
        "value": "FTNHQ-RP0205826"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, thank you soo much for this! I can confirm that it works. I'm baffled as to why on the older version it works without specifying the type, however not a big train smash on my end - I'm just going to quickly go and add some Type updates to the API calls.Once again, thank you soo much!

Comment: @ChristiaanRaubenheimer by older version, do you mean the older screen based API, or just another Acumatica version with the REST API? If you were creating the refund immediately before releasing it it's possible the state of the graph was not cleared so the type was still set to "Customer Refund"... this would explain why the system was able to find by reference nbr. only

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, I meant an older version of Acumatica, but still using the REST API, Acu version 19.100.0122, and REST API version Default > 18.200.001, however, your explanation around the state of the graph actually makes a lot of sense. In all cases, the document would have been created right before it was released. Again, thank you very much for this answer, it was a lifesaver! I've already updated all my code references in the external application, and have resolved all of the issues around this particular issue.